# Resources not loading in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-management-portal

I have been having trouble with the Azure Portal (portal.azure.com) for the past 36 hours. At first I couldn't even load the log in page but a DNS flush seemed to help (sporadically).  Now that I'm able to log in somewhat successfully, none of my resources/services are loading:

[image]

I'm an admin on the Azure account so I don't think it's a permissions issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note: I can get to a particular service just fine if I click on it from the dashboard.  But if the service/resource isn't on my dashboard then I can't get to it. Not even search will find it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be addressed with Azure support. Nothing can be resolved here...

Comment: Maybe try in a private/incognito window? This seems like something specific to your environment (there are no portal outages reported, and I double-checked - all is fine on my end).

Comment: I've tried Edge, Chrome, IE as well as private browsing in all of them, but no luck.  Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: can you use powershell to list your resource group?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jason.  Doing this gave me a big clue to the solution.  Even though I had successfully logged in to Azure using PS, it still told me my credentials had expired.  Running "Clear-AzureProfile –Force" fixed everything for me.  Or...it could all be coincidence.  Works great now though!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the wrong/expired credentials were cached somewhere on my machine. After logging in to PowerShell and running:

```
Clear-AzureProfile –Force
```

the issue went away.  As a side note, I constantly have to log in and out of Visual Studio between my home account and my work account.  I noticed that something went wrong the other day and I had to completely restart Visual Studio multiple times.  I think this may have been the culprit.

Of course this could still be coincidence and it could have been a problem with my ISP the whole time.

Hope this helps someone else down the road!

Answer (score 0):

I too had a similar issue. I recently had created a new Azure account other than the one i use every day.

I started using both the accounts, and suddenly my old account Azure portal wouldn't load.

I tried the first answer's solution, but it did not help.

I just changed the browser through which i access the portal. Keep in mind i never used this other browser ever to access my Azure portal.
And it worked fine in the other browser.

Answer (score -1):

There are different possibilities-

1. It could be browser specific issue. Try accessing Azure portal using a different browser.
2. It could be because of firewall settings in your network. Try accessing Azure portal in an outside network.
3. You could also try to access resources through powershell or CLI. If you cannot see there, I would suggest to check out the status of your subscription.

Regards,

Vaibhav Gujral